# When should I initialise subview using iOS autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've got some trouble using autolayout.

My class `MyView` extends `UIScrollView` and adds an `UIImageView` to `MyView.view` in the `init` method. Constraints are also set to the subview

```
    self.imageView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    let views:[NSObject : AnyObject] = ["imgView": self.imageView]
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[imgView]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[imgView]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
```

My `UIViewController`'s subclass contains `MyView` as subview and constraints are set in the storyboard.

I'd like to set the `UIImage` of `MyView`'s `UIImageView` **before** the ViewController is presented. The problem is, that I'm not sure where to set the image.

When setting the image in `func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)`, the constraints are not yet applied. When setting in `func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)` or `func updateViewConstraints()`, it's too late...

**UPDATE:**

As @kdogisthebest pointed out, it's ok to load the image before the constraints are applied, because the subviews resize automatically.

Unfortunately it seems this is not true for `UIScrollView`... I tried to change the superview of `MyView` to `UIView` and the resizing works as described. According to some quick research, `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` should do the trick, but it didn't work.

Comment: Should it really matter? You have pinned the UIImageView on all sides to it's superview. It will be that size regardless. If you set the image before that it will fit the image and redraw as if you had just set it. The only difference now is how the image loaded: network or local.

Comment: yes, it will be the size of the superview, but the superview's size is not correct, because the constraints are not yet applied

Comment: When the constraints are applied though it will call `layoutSubviews` which will redraw the UIImageView & the image. to the new size. I do this a lot in my table cells. I set the images before i add constraints & it displays fine.

Answer (score 0):

When the constraints are applied or `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` is called after updating constraints it will call `layoutSubviews` which will redraw the UIImageView & the image. to the new size. I guess calling `setImage` later would avoid an unnecessary draw.

I do this a lot in my table cells. I set the images before I add constraints & it displays fine.

The important thing to note is that as long as the UIImageView's size is changed, be it by constraint or `setFrame`, the image inside of it is redrawn as well to accommodate the size of the UIImageView.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems this is not true for `UIScrollView`... I tried to change the superview of  `MyView` to `UIView` and the resizing works as you described. According to some quick research, `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` should do the trick, but it didn't work